# Best way to implement two-way web video conferencing feature?

Tags: video-streaming, jmf, video-conferencing

I want to develop a website that provides **two-way web video conferencing** feature? The video delay should not be more than **1 second on a 56-kbps** internet connection.

I just know the name of JMF (Java Media Framework).

**Q1.** What are the other APIs that I can use for this?

**Q2.** Out of those APIs, Which APIs you think will not add a delay of more than 1 second on a 56-kbps internet connection?

As all the APIs would be new to me and this is very urgent project, I cannot go and try every API so if anyone has practical experience in this area then his/her help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want a framework to help take a look at tokbox. http://www.tokbox.com/

Comment: While I cannot offer suggestions on platforms or software, please take into account the maximum bandwidth a user on 56 kbps can handle. Generally the average throughput I've seen lately on 56k modems is around 5-8KB/s, so you may have to convert down the video on the fly and transmit that to a user.

Comment: What sort of frame rate are you expecting to get on dial up? Upload speeds are much less than download. So if the connection at both ends is 56kbs (v92) then the upload speed is about 33kbs so each end can only send data at an absolute maximum of 33kbs and usually less than that. sending anything other than real small real slow and real low quality video is near impossible Why are you limiting it to that speed. not many people are left on dial up anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of open source project for video conferencing in java with jmf.

I am providing you the link of one [Video Conferencing Project in Java](http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2013/07/video-conferencing-project-in-java.html)

Look into these 2 files

```
AVReceive2.java
AVTransmit2.java
```

You will have a good idea of jmf api.